# ibridgepy ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_IBCpp)

Tags: python-3.x, interactive-brokers

Starting to play with ibridgepy and run into the follow exception following the [tutorial](http://www.ibridgepy.com/tutorials/):

```
runfile('/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/IBridgePy_Mac/RUN_ME.py', wdir='/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/IBridgePy_Mac')
Reloaded modules: IBridgePy
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-2e91494ffd7b>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/IBridgePy_Mac/RUN_ME.py', wdir='/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/IBridgePy_Mac')

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/IBridgePy_Mac/RUN_ME.py", line 35, in <module>
    exec(script)

  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>

  File "/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/IBridgePy_Mac/IBridgePy/quantopian.py", line 1, in <module>
    from IBridgePy import IBCpp

ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_IBCpp)
```

I'm using MacOS 10.9.5 and Anaconda/Spyder